# How to implement and run this jQuery function and run that function in php code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
(function () {jQuery.fn.field = function (inputName, value) {

    if (typeof inputName !== "string") return false;
    var $inputElement = jQuery(this).find("input[name*=" + inputName + "]");




    if (typeof value === "undefined" && $inputElement.length >= 1) {
        switch ($inputElement.attr("type")) {
            case "checkbox":
                return $inputElement.is(":checked");

            case "radio":
                var result;
                $inputElement.each(function (i, val) {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) result = $(this).val();
                });
                return result;

            default:
                return $inputElement.val();
        }
    } else {
        switch ($inputElement.attr("type")) {
            case "checkbox":
                $inputElement.attr({
                    checked: value
                });
                break;
            case "radio":
                $inputElement.each(function (i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() == value) $(this).attr({
                        checked: true
                    });
                });
                break;
            case undefined:                   
            break;
            default:
                $inputElement.val(value);
                break;
        }
        return $inputElement;
    }
};'
```

and try to run this in foreach php code :

```
<script>




                                    jQuery("#1133156434").field('field1', 'kdweb');
                                    </script>
```

I get message :

`TypeError: jQuery(...).` field is not a function
error source line:

```
jQuery("#1133156434").field('field1', 'kdweb');
```

So where should i paste definition of the function or maybe i should run it in `document ready {}`. Now i have this function in the begining of html file

Comment: wrap the php output in a `jQuery.ready(function(){})`

Comment: Really .. `jQuery("#1133156434").field('fie...` REALLY??

Comment: WhatYou are getting this exception because you are using the function incorrectly. but ... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because you are using the function incorrectly.

I dont understand a lot of what you want to do ... but use the function like this:

```
field('field1', 'kdweb');
```

Comment: in fiddle it works. I have to use it like ('nameoftheform').field('nameoffield','value')

Comment: i think it is a problem of scope i put the same what in fiddle in the head of the page and the code in php somewhere below in page Should i wrap the function or the code where i use the function this actually i did it and no result still type error

Comment: So... Now I have no idea what is your issue... Edit Your question or create a new one! I answered that question maybe the next too :)